# Как мне перезаписать файл зашифрованным содержимым средствами openssl

Tags: openssl

Я хочу зашифровать файл, с помощью openssl. Мне надо его зашифровать, и перезаписать в файл, с тем же именем, что и был. Но если я пишу так.
`-openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pbkdf2 -in C://ZeD_Crypto//test.txt -out C://ZeD_Crypto//test.txt` то у меня он шифрует непонятно как, а когда я пытаюсь его дешифровать, то выдает непонятную ошибку.

Как мне сделать шифрование файлов, без изменения его имени?

Answer (score 1):

В openssl нельзя одновременно читать файл и писать в него. Вам нужно сначала записать шифртекст во временный файл, затем переписать этот файл вместо исходника.

Не знаю, каким шеллом вы пользуетесь, в `bash` это может выглядеть вот как:

```
src=./test.txt
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pbkdf2 -in "$src" -out "$tmpfile"
mv "$tmpfile" "$src"
```

Этот скрипт заменит содержимое файла `test.txt` зашифрованным содержимым в кодировке `base64`

Расшифровка

```
src=./test.txt
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pbkdf2 -in "$src" -out "$tmpfile"
mv "$tmpfile" "$src"
```

Этот скрипт возвращает в исходный файл расшифрованное содержимое.